# libvirt and network filtering with nat - iptables overrides

Tags: iptables, kvm-virtualization, nat, libvirt

At first, I want to say: I know, it was done initially wrong and I want to avoid doing everything again from the scratch because of general downtime.

I am running libvirt/KVM on RHEL. I've got VM which runs with NAT networking profile (default one). I've set up port forwarding etc from host via sysconfig/iptables, everything is fine.

But if libvird daemon reloads for some internal reason, or receives `SIGHUP` - it reloads iptables configuration and adds rules from it's filtering profiles **i.e. everything works as designed and documented** ([libvirt and firewall](http://libvirt.org/firewall.html) + [libvirt nwfilter documentation](http://libvirt.org/formatnwfilter.html)) - there is no problem with SW, this is configuration issue.

But some rules introduce `REJECT`s before i need it and I can't connect to the machine via forwarded ports as seen below:

[image]

after running `service iptables restart` - everything will work as before.

Is there a way to force libvirt to change order of these two or disable these particular ones?

Maybe someone faced exactly the same issue and has answer ready.

Thanks

Comment: I use firewalld on my current systems. It plays much more nicely with libvirt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own NAT network instead which means libvirt won't add any firewall rules. See the [Custom NAT-based Network](https://jamielinux.com/docs/libvirt-networking-handbook/custom-nat-based-network.html) on this [libvirt Networking Handbook](https://jamielinux.com/docs/libvirt-networking-handbook/).

Comment: Looks like this is only workaround available :)

Answer (score 3):

I feel your pain. I really wish libvirt supported this better.

Create a script that applies the port forwarding firewall rules on your guest. Be sure to use `iptables -I` so that your rules are inserted before libvirt's REJECT rule.

You need to use [hooks](http://libvirt.org/hooks.html) to run that script each time libvirt starts or is reloaded.

Also, you should make sure that the rules for libvirt and your port forwarding aren't saved in */etc/sysconfig/iptables*. Let libvirt and your hook set those up.

Comment: yup, a known issue with libvirt, which is why I always recommend sticking to bridging

Comment: aha, so far only bridging is a good solution